# Java characters not being evaluated Parantheses, Plus and Space

Tags: java

I have a snippet of code for evaluating valid phone number characters.  Digits and dashes are being allowed, but parantheses, plus sign, and space are not.  Do I need to use an escape character for these to get them to evaluate correctly?

```
 // All valid phone numbers would contain the numeric digits and - sign

for (int pos = 0, len = theValue.length(); pos < len; ++pos) {
    if (! Character.isDigit(theValue.charAt(pos))
            && theValue.charAt(pos) != '-' && theValue.charAt(pos) != '(' && theValue.charAt(pos) != ')' 
            && theValue.charAt(pos) != '+' && theValue.charAt(pos) != ' ' 
            && theValue.charAt(pos) != 'x' && theValue.charAt(pos) != 'X') {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: Use some RegExp

Comment: The code that you have shown us looks OK.  Please provide a MCVE ... so that we can run your code and see for ourselves.

Comment: (But,  no you should not need escapes for any of those characters.)